# Why is IE7 not rendering this absolutely positioned element correctly?

Tags: css, html, css-position, internet-explorer-7

There is a plethora of questions and forum posts concerning IE7's behavior with absolutely positioned elements. Out of the dozen or so that I've read, none of the advice contained in them has helped in my particular situation. I'm starting to wonder if it's because I'm using the HTML5 shiv. Regardless, I'm hoping someone might have some insight into the behavior I'm seeing.

**Firefox 5, Safari 5, Chrome 12, IE8/9**
[image: The correct rendering]

**Internet Explorer 7**
[image: The incorrect rendering]

In a nutshell, you mouseover one of the nav menu items, it drops down a div with the advanced menu, yadda yadda yadda... The hidden div is positioned absolutely, however in IE7 it snaps to the edge of the menu item you highlight. Everywhere else, it displays below it, properly.

I am using the remy's HTML5 shiv. I am including CSS to "block" the following elements: `header`, `nav`, `article`, `footer`, `section`, `aside`, `figure`, and `figcaption`.

Here's the relevant HTML and CSS:

```
<nav>
   //other nav divs
   <div id="kb">
      <a href="/kb/"><span>knowledge base</span></a>
      <div id="kb_expand" class="nav_expand">
         <div>
            //more options...
            <section>
               <h2><a href="">Exchange</a></h2>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Exchange Setup</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Calendar Basics</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Calendar Sharing</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Resources</a></li>
               </ul>
            </section>
            //more options...
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   //other nav divs
 </nav>


nav{float:right;margin-top:-26px;text-align:right;width:945px;padding:9px 0 10px}
nav > div{display:inline;padding:8px 0 11px}
.nav_expand{display:none;position:absolute;background:url('images/shadow-south.png') repeat-x bottom;padding-bottom:7px}
.nav_expand div{text-align:left;background:url('images/nav-background.png') repeat-y;width:925px;padding:5px 10px 10px;color:#FFF;margin-top:10px;overflow:hidden}
```

I appreciate any insight anyone can provide! Thanks!

Comment: I can't check right now but I'm not sure the selector `nav > div` works correctly in IE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided to drop support for Internet Explorer 7. There is an absolute position bug in IE7 that is not worth fixing for our market share of visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem a few weeks ago, which drove me nuts.

I googled `position absolute ie7`, that kinda thing, and tried making all `position:absolute` to `position:relative`, and tweeking `margin-right -left -top -bottom` - didn't work.

Then I fumbled around with the z-index, also to no avail.

My solution was to give every element a style of `position:absolute`. My problem was with some divs on top of a google map. A `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%` did the trick. Luckily I didn't depend on any of the divs being relative positioned, but I THINK! it should be possible with some JS (not just getElementById('style)' at it's the same thing, but something `layers.pos`.)

My best bet would be to try and give your kb a `position:absolute`, then tweek around.

Try googling `z-index ie7 position absolute bug`.

On a side note, if you're not familiar with it, http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ is a true gem for automated screenshots, and even live VNC to test your site in any browser/os combination. They have a free trial, good for at least a few trial runs. Also Firebug is great for on-the-fly testing of style changes without actually modifying the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a similar thing to what you describe, took me hours to figure it out and in the end I don't know why it would cause the problem but I suspect it's a bug rather than a feature. I had `text-align: right;` on my first level `ul` and then `text-align: left;` on the second level. Removing it from the first level solved the problem. To achieve the same effect (as I have anchors rendered as blocks) I just put text-align on the anchor instead of the `ul`.

Hope that helps. I presume you've moved on by now, but would be interested to see if this was anything to do with your problem.